# How to return an integer from MySQL DB query in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my Laravel controller I use the following code:

```
$usernotes = DB::select('SELECT note_id FROM note_user WHERE user_id = 1');
```

This is supposed to fetch the `note_id` from my many-to-many table, and it does. But `return $usernotes;` outputs

```
[{"paper_id":15}]
```

This looks like an array or a string, but I just need a plain integer `15` so I can put it into something like

```
$somevariable = someModel::find($usernotes)
```

`$usernotes` doesn't look like a number and running the above line gives me an error:

> ErrorException in helpers.php line 740: Object of class stdClass could
>   not be converted to string

How can I return just that number `15` out of that string?

Comment: you can use ->get()->toArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're running the query, you're getting a collection of objects. To get the ID, you need to get property of one of those objects. So try this:

```
$id = $usernotes->first()->note_id; // or maybe this will work $id = $usernotes[0]->note_id;
```

Or this:

```
DB::table('note_user')->select('note_id')->where('user_id', 1)->first()->note_id;
```

If you're using a model:

```
NoteUser::find(1)->note_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for a set of great solutions! I forgot to mention in my question the scenario where there there is more than one `note_id`. I am trying to get `DB::table('note_user')->select('note_id')->where('user_id', 1)->first()->note_id;` to work with `->all()` like this `DB::table('note_user')->select('note_id')->where('user_id', 1)->all()->note_id;` but it gives me an error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()". Is there a way to make this work with multiple `note_id`'s?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but try `$notes = DB::table('note_user')->where('user_id', 1)->all('note_id')`. If this isn't working, try `get('note_id')` instead. If this isn't working too, use Eloquent to use `all()`. When you got working solution, just iterate over the result collection with something like this `foreach($notes as $note){ echo $note->note_id; }`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this, if you are using a model:

`$department_id = Department::select('id')->where('dep_name','=', 'mydepartmentname')->first()->id;`

`$department_id` - is the name of our variable we want to assign value from the database. 
Department is the model `id` - the part in the end is the field name in the table from which you you are drawing data. Hope this helps you.